# HP probook 4540s stuck at the first screen?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Here is what happened:

1. I installed Windows and it made a 100MB partition
2. I booted with the Windows CD again, formatted the 100MB partition and system partition then installed Windows again
3. After that it worked so I installed drivers normally
4. I booted into partition tool and deleted the 100 partition and merged it into system partition
5. Now the PC stuck at the first screen I can't even enter the BIOS setup
6. I tried to unplug the HDD then managed to enter the BIOS setup

How can I make PC boot and reinstall Windows?

Comment: That 100MB partition is your boot partition... Why on earth would you delete a partition created by the Windows installer and not expect something to break?

Comment: Sorry , where us your answer?!

Comment: Journeyman Geek has the right answer... Reinstall and don't delete the boot partition.

Comment: I can't even access BIOS setup with the internal HDD pluged

Answer (score 1):

This, is, quite bluntly what happens when you have no idea what you're doing. [That 100 mb partition is where the bootloader is](http://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/). A reasonable guess is that its trying to fastboot and failing since it can't find the bootloader.

Try holding down or tapping escape (for getting to the system setup) or <kbd>F10</kbd> *while* you're turning it on. Tapping is the correct thing, holding down should work as an alternative.

If you get into bios *don't delete the 100mb partition on the next install*. And make sure fastboot is turned off before doing anything like this.

Comment: That doesn't work , I select boot selector and it flash then nothing